# How to find number of unique elements in a 2D array in java? Is there any method present there?

Tags: java, methods, char

I want to calculate no. of distinct elements (char datatype) in a 2D array in java. When I tried  `Arrays.stream(arr).distinct().count()` it gave wrong ans and seems like it is also taking some garbage value as it is returning 3 when the ans was 2, here is a screenshot of that.[Here is the photo, when I debugged my code, it seems like it is only checking for the 1st row for distinct values but that too in wrong way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lUH9.png)

Is there any method to find no of distinct elements in a 2D array.

Comment: Please add your code and sample values as formatted text to your question. It should be a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the stream is the array, you used 2D array so when you stream it you get a 1D array. So you need to use flatMap on the stream to create a stream of your basic type.

Answer (score 0):

If `arr` is a 2D array, eg `String[][] arr = {{"1", "2"}, {"2", "4"}, {"3", "4"}}`

Then `Arrays.stream(arr)` is giving you a `Stream<String[]>` where each item in the stream is a 1 dimensional array of Strings.

If you want to distinguish between the actual elements in the 2D array then you also need to `flatMap` each `String[]` in your initial stream. Like this: `Arrays.stream(arr).flatMap(Arrays::stream)` which will return a `Stream<String>` of all elements in each of the subarrays for which you find the number of distinct values with `Arrays.stream(arr).flatMap(Arrays::stream).distinct().count()`